# How to use LINQ to combine two or more collections into one collection

Tags: c#, linq, join, collections

I have three collections

```
var col1 = new {Name1 = "Frank", ID1 = 123, ABC = "abc"};
var col2 = new {Name2 = "Harry", ID2 = 456, XYZ = "xyz"};
var col3 = new {Name3 = "Bob"};
```

I want to create a fourth collection that brings those three collections together.

Using the three collections as the example, I would like the fourth collection to "look" like this:

```
+===================+
| FirstName | Ident |
+===================+
| Frank     | 123   |
+-------------------+
| Harry     | 456   |
+-------------------+
| Bob       |       |
+-------------------+
```

I don't even know if it's possible, but I'm trying to figure out if I can use LINQ to merge the tables by mapping the fields of col1, col2, and col3 to the fields of the fourth collection.

Psuedo-code to, hopefully, clarify what I'm trying to explain:

```
var col4 = from c1 in col1, c2 in col2, c3 in col3
     select new {FirstName = (c1.Name1, c2.Name2, c3.Name3), Ident = (c1.ID1, c2.ID2);
```

If this is possible, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: col1, col2 & col3 are not collections, just anonymous objects with 3(1) properties.

Comment: Oops... I will edit my question next time I'm in front of my computer. Until then, what I meant was that my collections have the structure as I described in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq Union. I've faked up the initialization since your example doesn't really have collections, but still retain the anonymous nature of the elements since I think this is what you're intending.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var dummys = new List<int>(); dummys.Add(1);
    var col1 = from dummy in dummys
               select new { Name1 = "Frank", ID1 = 123, ABC = "abc" };
    var col2 = from dummy in dummys
               select new { Name2 = "Harry", ID2 = 456, XYZ = "xyz" };
    var col3 = from dummy in dummys
               select new { Name3 = "Bob" };

    var col4 = col1.Select(c=> new { FirstName=c.Name1, Ident=new Nullable<int>(c.ID1)})
        .Union(col2.Select(c=> new { FirstName=c.Name2, Ident=new Nullable<int>(c.ID2)}))
        .Union(col3.Select(c=> new { FirstName=c.Name3, Ident=new Nullable<int>()}));

    foreach (var c in col4) {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for LINQ Union operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx